# Will I be allowed to enter Ireland if I was deported from UK

Tags: ireland, removal, deportation

I'm EU citizen, in 2015 I was deported from UK and got a 10 year ban. The forms i got are IS.165 and ISE.312 yes I have spent time in UK prison and got deported. Question is will I be allowed to enter Ireland by air. My deportation documents don't mention nothing about Ireland.

Comment: They gave you some paperwork, what number form is in the upper right corner.  Probably something like IS98.  Without knowing your paperwork, the question is 'unclear'.  Voting to close until the question is fleshed out more.

Comment: According to https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-13-deportation, it can happen when a foreign citizen is convicted of a sufficiently serious crime, or on the order of a Secretary of State.  But it is also possible to OP has mixed up deportation and administrative removal.

Comment: Since you can drive from Ireland to Northern Ireland without passport checks I can't image you being let in.

Comment: The forms i got are IS.165 and ISE.312 yes I have spent time in UK prison and got deported. Anyway no one can answer my question? Thanks

Comment: @Walter, thanks for the update about what you were served; you can go to Ireland despite the UK ban; if you are doing that to use the Common Travel Area, there can be horrible consequences. Be careful!

Comment: forgot to add...  You cannot go to any of the protectorates...

Comment: @Gayot Fow, but I'm not planning going to UK through Ireland. My mate in Dublin is offering me a job starting next month in Dublin and that's the reason I want to go there. Anyway is Ireland British protectorate?

Comment: @Walter Nope. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protectorate#British_protectorates. Ireland is an independent nation.

Comment: I just read this article and I'm a bit confused now. http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/IRELAND-UK%20ACCORD%20TO%20FURTHER%20SECURE%20THE%20COMMON%20TRAVEL%20AREA

Comment: I'm afraid that they won't let me in.http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/1975/si/128/made/en/print

Comment: @Walter, protectorates are about anything in the archipelago except the ROI and the UK.

Comment: So, here's what confuses me: try it. What happens? They let you enter, or they don't. Let's say they don't let you in, for some reason, because of the ban. If you do everything by the book (visa, passport, etc, whatever Ireland requires) they aren't going to imprison you just for applying. Then, you'll know.

Comment: @CGCampbell, even more straight-forward, the OP can apply for entry clearance from the comfort of his own home.  Removes all doubt and anxiety...  Done and dusted.

Comment: @GayotFow wouldn't they just reject entry clearance for an EU citizen as irrelevant?

Comment: @CMaster it might clear the first sift with a flag for a supervisor to look at. They will ultimately consider it. The OP will get an entry clearance or a refusal with no wasted airfares and no admin removal.  OP's choice.

Comment: @GayotFow Man, Guernsey, etc are dependencies, surely, not protectorates? Don't think the UK's had one of those for a while...

Answer (score 7):

Given that you are an EU citizen (and **not** dual citizen of a non-eu country, which could result into different outcomes), there are two potential ways forward. You have the right to enter any EU country except where prohibited (i.e., UK in this case), so just go and hope for the best. Or, you work on undoing the ban and travel freely without any potential problems.

Given your history, I suggest you **do not** take the first action to enter Ireland.

Why? As part of Common Travel Area (CTA), since 2011 Ireland and the UK share information including, but not limited to, biometric and biographic information which includes legal hisotry. According to Irish government [agencies](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_abroad/freedom_of_movement_within_the_eu/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html):

> The Common Travel Area also involves some co-operation on matters
>   relating to immigration issues. A third country national, for example,
>   may be refused permission to enter Ireland if it is their intention to
>   travel onwards to the UK and they would not qualify for admission to
>   the UK under the Aliens (Amendment) Order 1975. Irish immigration
>   officers have the power to carry out checks on people arriving in the
>   State from the UK and to refuse them entry to the State on the same
>   grounds as apply to people arriving from outside the Common Travel
>   Area. These checks are carried out selectively.
>
> In December 2011, the Irish and UK governments agreed measures to
>   secure the external Common Travel Area border. This includes
>   exchanging biographic and biometric visa data and co-operating on
>   establishing information about failed asylum seekers. There is a joint
>   UK-Ireland Common Travel Area Forum which implements these measures.

While the checks are selective, it might be worth noting that simply presenting your passport will give instant access to your deportation and legal records which, consequently, could lead you into further trouble if the border officers are not satisfied with your explanations, thus leading into entry refusal or worse potential deportation from Ireland as well.

At a more subtle level, to an Irish immigration officer, you cannot convince (**if asked**) that you will not use Ireland to enter the UK. Why? Simply because there are no checks to enter Northern Ireland (UK) from Republic of Ireland. Such entry is essentially what your ban prohibits.

A discussion at [FlyerTalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/u-k-ireland/1583476-deportation.html) might be helpful since the case is somewhat similar i.e., travel freedom of EU national with criminal record in the UK.

*Disclaimer: I am not an immigration expert, just curious and the information above is collected by a quick web search.*

Comment: How would the situation be different for a dual EU/non-EU citizen?