# Can I go to Ireland if I'm on a 10 year ban from the UK?

Tags: ireland, deportation, common-travel-area

I have been convicted of a serious criminal offence in the UK and received a 10 year ban. I'm an EEA national. I want to move to Dublin. I have no intention of returning to the UK, but will I be allowed entry into Ireland?

Comment: Questions about permanent relocation belong on the sister Q&A site expatriates.stackexchange.com. The moderators might move this question for you. See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61077/13639 and https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31546/13639